# Set Number format in excel using interop

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, interop

Using the method below I can load a row at time into an Excel file.  Once all the rows are loaded into Excel.

A column holds alphanumeric characters,if cell content is numbers its aligned to left side otherwise aligned to right side.I need to always aligned to right side.

I would like change the format of cell to Text.

```
  private void AddExcelRows(string startRange, int rowCount,int colCount, object values)
    {
        _range = _sheet.get_Range(startRange, _optionalValue);
        _range = _range.get_Resize(rowCount, colCount);
        _range.set_Value(_optionalValue, values);
    }
```

How can I set cell format as Text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text format is the '@' symbol, so:

```
_range.NumberFormat = "@";
```

should do the trick.